# Hold off before making guns

Tags: riddle, visual

The images below are connected by a single word:

[image: Maid]

[image: Rail Way Track]

[image: Wind Farm]

[image: Hat/Coat Stand]

[image: First Place Ribbon]

[image: Blood Pressure Cuff]

[image: Milkshake]

What is the word, and what are the connections?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can I give a

> hand

With connections

> handmaid
>  handrail
>  farmhand (from wind farm)
>  handstand
>  firsthand
>  handcuff
>  handshake - thanks @APrough

Title: Hold off before making guns

> handhold/hold hands, offhand/handoff, beforehand, (handmade)/handmaking, handguns

Over and out.

Comment: last one *shake